# Pass two objects with bidirectional One to One relationship into one Thymeleaf form

Tags: java, spring, jpa, thymeleaf

I'm working on a JPA project in which I have two models: TableDecor and Product Tag, which look like this:

```
@Entity(name="table_decor")
public class TableDecor {
    @Id
    @IdConstraint
    private String id;
    @Positive
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int width;
    @Positive
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int height;
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Color color;
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Fabric fabric;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "seller",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "table_decor_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "seller_id"))
    private List<Seller> sellers;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="producer_id")
    private Producer producer;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ProductTag productTag;

    // getters, setters
```

```
@Entity(name="product_tag")
@Table
public class ProductTag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private ProductState productState;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private float price;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "table_decor_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private TableDecor tableDecor;

    // getters, setters
```

As you can see they're connected with each other with bidirectional one to one relationship. Since one can't exist without another, how can I create a Thymeleaf add form that could create both objects at the same time? The controller function currently looks like this:

```
   @GetMapping("/table-decor/add")
    public String showAddForm(TableDecor decorToAdd, ProductTag productTag) {
        return "table-decor-add";
    }

    @PostMapping("/table-decor/add-new")
    public String addTableDecor(@Valid TableDecor decorToAdd, @Valid ProductTag productTag, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            return "table-decor-add";
        }
        decorToAdd.setProductTag(productTag);
        tableDecorService.addTableDecor(decorToAdd);
        model.addAttribute("allTableDecor", tableDecorService.getAllTableDecor());
        return "redirect:/table-decor";
```

and the form:

```
<form action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/table-decor/add-new}">
    <div><input name="id" type="text" th:value="${tableDecor.id}"></div>
    <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('tableDecor.id')}" th:errors="*{tableDecor.id}"></span>
    <div><input name="width" type="text" th:value="${tableDecor.width}"></div>
    <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('tableDecor.width')}" th:errors="*{tableDecor.width}"></span>
    <div><input name="height" type="text" th:value="${tableDecor.height}"></div>
    <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('tableDecor.height')}" th:errors="*{tableDecor.height}"></span>
    <select name="color">
        <option th:each="color : ${T(jee.labs.lab05.domain.Color).values()}"
                th:text="${color}"
                th:value="${tableDecor.color}">
        </option>
    </select>
    <select name="fabric">
        <option th:each="fabric : ${T(jee.labs.lab05.domain.Fabric).values()}"
                th:text="${fabric}"
                th:value="${tableDecor.fabric}">
        </option>
    </select>
    <select name="productState">
        <option th:each="productState : ${T(jee.labs.lab05.domain.ProductState).values()}"
                th:text="${productState}"
                th:value="${productTag.productState}">
        </option>
    </select>
    <div><input name="price" type="text" th:value="${productTag.price}"></div>
    <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('productTag.price')}" th:errors="*{productTag.price}"></span>
    <div><input type="submit" th:value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thymeleaf is responsible for a view layer whereas domain entities are at a different (persistence) layer. Thymeleaf doesn't need to know anything about them being bidirectional or whatever. Just create a form that has input fields for the attributes of both objects. Then create a DTO for that thymeleaf form and once you have received it in your controller, map it to both entity objects separately and persist those in the service/persistence layer.

Comment: @JAsgarov okay, that helped a lot. Thank you :)